# How to count no of agents who have spent X days in the system in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am building invoice processing simulation model. invoice creation date is the source generation date . Every Invoice will have due date which varies. 31 days, 60 days, 90 days.
Any agent generated at resource I can add these days to the source generation date and get due date. Next step is at point I should know how many invoices are past due date .
e.g 10 invoices are between 1- 5 days, 15 invoices are between 6 to 20 days etc. I have created three variable in the agent population. Start time, end time and Due time
double `DueTime= (time()-dateToTime (due_date));`

This is calculating DueTime correctly.

Then in the main I am trying to compute the count of agent

```
int x_1_5=  count( invoices, p -> p.DueTime >1 && p.DueTime<=5 );
age_1_5=String.valueOf(x_1_5);
```

This is giving me 0 as output.
Is there a way to do do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only calculating your `DueDate` variable once at the start of the agent creation.

You need to turn it into a function `getDueTime()` that returns the double value when called. Just paste `return (time()-dateToTime (due_date));` into the function and then in your counter call

`int x_1_5=  count( invoices, p -> p.getDueTime() >1 && p.getDueTime()<=5 );`

Variables do not act like functions and vice versa.

Comment: Pls see the above snapshot . Tried this approach but getting error

Comment: Fixed this . Function should return value and forgot to check that  return value option

Answer (score -1):

Tried this approach. Created function in Invoice agent and then calling it on the main inside another function. But it is throwing error .

[image]

[image]